# Default Concurrency strategy for Query Cache in Hibernate using ECache

Tags: java, database, hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

I was wondering about the default concurrency strategy for the Query level caching in Hibernate if we do not provide it explicitly. I have gone through the link https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache but unable to find the exact solution. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SessionFactory object is thread safe, and it manages L2 cache, that's why you can assume that all L2 cache is thread safe. This technique is called instance confinement, you assume that only SessionFactory object instance will operate on L2 cache.

With L1 cache you have make sure that you manage your Session object properly and you not publish it anywhere, as it's not thread safe.

Comment: I did not get your answer. Please elaborate.

Comment: There's no hibernate query cache concurrency strategy, because hibernate doesn't come with L2 cache. It has interfaces to L2 cache, but you have to add declaratively provider that you want to use e.g. Ehcache. Session objects then are querying L2 cache to get an entity, but it's up to specific provider, how the concurrent access is being handled.

Comment: On your side you only specify locking strategy and let the provider to worry about concurrency.